# To show that the only nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$ which is both open and closed in $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

To show that the only nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$ which is both open and closed in $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$.

Let $A$ be a non empty subset of $\Bbb R$ which is both open and closed. Let $x \in A$. Then $(x- \epsilon ,x+ \epsilon) \subset A$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Then how to bring the contradiction by putting in the fact that $A$ cannot be simultaneously open and closed!!

Comment: This is kind of difficult to prove directly from first principles. The proof is that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so such a thing is impossible. $\mathbb{R}$ is connected since it's homeomorphic to an open interval, which is connected. This is proved using the least upper bound property of the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, and the proof is a bit involved. See Munkres section 24.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70415/showing-that-mathbbr-is-connected

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is nonempty, closed, and open (clopen), then $A$ and $\mathbb{R}-A$ are both open. Therefore, the pair $$A,\mathbb{R}-A$$

is a separation of $\mathbb{R}$, which contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.
To see that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, you can check [Showing that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70415/showing-that-mathbbr-is-connected).

Comment: This is more like a link than an answer?

Comment: Not really, it's an answer that uses a simple fact.  A link was provided only if that fact needed to be proved seperately