# Continuity in metric space if $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

let the standard metric $d(x,y)=|y-x|$ and  $\rho_{disc}$ be the discrete metric defined by

$${\displaystyle \rho (x,y)={\begin{cases}1&{\mbox{if}}\ x\neq y,\\0&{\mbox{if}}\ x=y\end{cases}}}$$ Let $V=(\mathbb{R},\rho_{disc}$) and $W=(\mathbb{R},d)$ be two metric spaces (that has $\mathbb{R}$ as underlying sets, but given by two different metrices as written).

1. Show that every function $h:V\rightarrow W$ is continuous
2. Show that a function $f:W\rightarrow V$ is continuous if and only if  it is constant.

**So far**

1)

I have a result (though I have to explain it) that states in a discrete metric space that all subsets are open. This implies that if a set $X$ has a discrete metric then all mappings $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to some set $Y$ are continuous. In this case $V$ has a discrete metric and thus it is sufficient to argue that in a discrete metric space that all subsets are open.

We can translate the issue into a ball has radius $r$. If $r<1$ then the only point it contains is the point it's centred on. So any single point has a ball of some radius around it containing only that point. This is the same thing as $B_{0<r<1}(x)=\{x\}$, so we know that every singleton is open.

2)

This one I do not really know how to approach and the fact that it is a bi implication does not help me.

Comment: (2) Take a point $y$ in the range of $f$. This is $f^{-1})(\{y\})$ is non-empty. If $f$ is continuous, and since $\{y\}$ is open, we must have that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is open. Since $\{y\}^{c}$ is also open, then $f^{-1}(\{y\}^c)=(f^{-1}(\{y\}))^c$ is also open. Since $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is connected and since $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is non-empty, we must have $f^{-1}(\{y\}^c)$ empty. Therefore $f\equiv y$.

Comment: @plop I was told that I could use the supremum property on R directly or indirectly.

Comment: Yes, you can use it to replace the knowledge that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is connected. You could argue like this: We already have that $A=f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is open and non-empty. Pick $h\in A$. If the set of $L= \{x\in f^{-1}(\{y\}^c\mid\ x <h)$ is non-empty, then it would have a supremum. This supremum cannot be in $L$, since $L$ is open, but it cannot be in $A$ either, since $A$ is open. Therefore $L$ is empty. Next consider the set $U=\{x\mid -x\in f^{-1}(\{y\}^c),\ -x>h\}$. If $U$ is non-empty, then it has a supremum.

Comment: Again, since $U$ is open and since $A$ is open, then that supremum cannot be in $U$ nor in $A$. Therefore, $U$ is empty. It follows that $f^{-1}(\{y\}^c)$ is empty and therefore, $f\equiv y$.

Comment: @plop Is $A$ the one with the discrete metric? The notation is not that obvious when we define the standard metric as $d(x,y)=|y-x|$

Comment: $A$ is a subset of your  $W$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $f: W \to V$ be continuous. Let $\varepsilon = 1/2$. There exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $\rho(f(x),f(y)) < 1/2$ which implies that $f(x) = f(y)$. This shows that $f$ is piecewise contstant. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I am the absolut worst at $\epsilon$-style proofs.

Comment: I was told that I could use the supremum property on $\mathbb{R}$ directly or indirectly.

Comment: @user879295 What I would do is take some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and try to show that $f(x)=f(y)$ by partitioning their euclidean distance appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In general, a continuous non-constant function from a space $X$ to $V$ exists if and only if $X$ is a [disconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

Comment: I was told that I could use the supremum property on $\mathbb{R}$ directly or indirectly.

Comment: @user879295 Right, that would be one way to show that $\Bbb R$ is connected. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70423/81360).